# Override default text for derived Windows Form control

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

When you drag a new Button onto a Windows Form it is automatically assigned the text "button1". If you have a control that inherits button called "CustomButton" then that one is automatically assigned the text "customButton1" when added to a form.

Is it possible to make this text default to something else? For example, can I have the text default to "click me!" when the control is dragged onto a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to not use the standard `Text` property and make your own instead.

If you do that, you should override the `Text` property and apply `[Browsable(false)]`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing with a new property called ButtonText.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `Text` property in your derived control's constructor?

```
public CustomButton() {
    Text = "Click me!";
}
```

If you also want your text to appear as real default value (i.e. not bold in the property window), you should override the `Text` property and set a `DefaultValue`-Attribute:

```
[DefaultValue("Click me!")]
override string Text {
    get { return base.Text }
    set { base.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will help.

Comment: I tried something along these lines before posting and it seems as long as the property was called Text something overrode it's value when added to a form.